# JSTL <c:out> where the element value content have a space character

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to set the string for **value attribute** of HTML5 element using JSTL . Like below,

```
value=<c:out value="${input.content}"/>
```

But in here i have the spaces within content value. So its only getting the part of that string which beginning of string to first space place of the string.

Ex: if content = "My Input" then value becomes value = "My".

How can i fix this. Its pretty hard to change my code now. So is there have any way to fix this. Thanks. Im using jquery 2.* and HTML5.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A JSTL value can have spaces in the content; that is not the problem.

In the code you pasted, you are missing a quotation mark to start the value attribute.  Add it and your code should work fine:

You have:

```
value=<c:out value="${input.content}"/>
```

Should be:

```
value="<c:out value="${input.content}"/>
```

Comment: This still throws the error "Unterminated [&lt;form:option] tag"  because of the quotation mark inside quotation.